# Why is the Hubble Space Telescope mass increasing?

Tags: history, space-telescope, hubble

According to this [Youtube video](https://youtu.be/kFbug8as10U?t=400) I came to know that the mass of the [Hubble space telescope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hubble_Space_Telescope) has increased from the time of launch. What is making this mass increment? Are these the debris?